# How to get git diff (changed lines) in IntelliJ Idea plugin?

Tags: git, intellij-plugin

I need to get Git changed lines information in IntelliJ plugin. For example, I need to know line 1 and 2 was added and line 3 and 7 was deleted.

I tried this approach, but don't sure it's right

```
    val repositoryManager = GitRepositoryManager.getInstance(project)
    val changeListManager = ChangeListManager.getInstance(project)
    val changes = changeListManager.allChanges

    for (change in changes) {
        val beforeRevision = change.beforeRevision
        val afterRevision = change.afterRevision

        val beforeContent = beforeRevision?.content.toString()
        val afterContent = afterRevision?.content.toString()

        val progressManager = ProgressManager.getInstance()
        val progressIndicator = progressManager.progressIndicator

        val fragments = ComparisonManager.getInstance().compareChars(beforeContent, afterContent, ComparisonPolicy.DEFAULT, progressIndicator)


        val ranges = fragments.map {
            Range(it.startOffset1, it.endOffset1, it.startOffset2, it.endOffset2)
        }

        for (line in fragments) {
            val originalLineNumber = StringUtil.offsetToLineNumber(beforeContent, line.startOffset2)
            val modifiedLineNumber = StringUtil.offsetToLineNumber(afterContent, line.endOffset2)

            println(originalLineNumber)
        }
```

}